# Reading and interpreting a logical expression in a program

Tags: java, expression, logical-operators

How do you usually read logical expressions in a program? For example:

`(1 == x) && ( 2 > x++)? (x=1)`

What is the purpose of `?` and what is the way of thinking for generating the right answer for the expression?

Comment: That is not a valid expression in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement:

```
var value = (boolean expression) ? some value if `true` : some value if `false`
```

Is a special conditional statement which makes use of a [Ternary Operator](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/ternary-operator.html) (`?:`) to assign values, based on the boolean expression, to the variable.

It's a much more concise way of expressing this conditional statement:

```
var value;

//this is the boolean expression you evaluate before the question mark
if (boolean expression is true) {
    //this is what you assign after the question mark
    value = some value if true;
}
else {
    //this is what you assign after the colon
    value = some other value if false;
}
```

So based on your example (syntactically faulty btw), that would be something like:

```
if ((1 == x) && (2 > x++)){
    x = 1;
}
else {
    /*This is the value that would be put after the colon
     *(which is missing in your example, and would cause a compiler error)
     */
    x = some other value; 
}
```

Which would translate to:

```
x = (1 == x) && (2 > x++) ? 1 : some other value
```

Answer (score 1):

This statement does not even compile, `?` is used  with `:` as a ternary operator.

After `(x=1)` you should have the else branch, just an example:

`(1 == x) && ( 2 > x++) ? (x=1) : (x = 2)`

The way this boolean expression is evaluated is the following, suppose x is 1 :

1. `(1 == x)` = true
2. `(2 > x++)` = false
3. `true && false` = false

You expression will always be false regardless of the value of your x

Answer (score 1):

```
 (1 == x) && ( 2 > x++)? (x=1);
```

`?` stands for ternary operation. , if left of `?` is true then it follows immediate right side.

In your case if `( 2 > x++)` is true then value of `x` will be 1. but to travel towards `( 2 > x++)` your left expression have to be true which means `x==1`, so if 
`(1 == x)` is true and so`( 2 > x++)` is true then your overall condition to true.

Comment: Huh ?  x++ means the increment will happen ***after*** evaluation of x.  So `2>x++` is `2>1` is true.

Comment: @ErwinSmout , you are right,  i kind of missed it. Thanks man +1

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the relevant comments about ?: where the colon is ***required***, the following is also needed to "understand" the operation of the code in example :

Evaluation order of && implies that ´ ( 2 > x++) ´ will ***not*** be evaluated al all unless ´(1 == x)´ is true.  Meaning in particular that the side-effect from x++ will not occur.

´x=1´ is an ***assignment*** so at first glance that doesn't look like an expression that evaluates to a value, but in java assignments are themselves expressions that take on the value being assigned.